# Google Maps API control InfoWindows with Javascript after they are created

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying markers and info windows on a Google Map using the following (partial) code. I have a listener setup so that when you click a marker, the corresponding info window shows (attached to the marker).

My question is, how can I access the info windows outside of this listener? For example, if I wanted to write Javascript to arbitrarily choose an info window and display it over its marker, can I do that by using its ID somehow?

This code was mostly taken from Google example scripts.

```
var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

for (i=0; i<markerLength; i++){
    var position=new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
    setmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
        return function(){
            infowindow.setContent(infocontent[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: One way would be to trigger a click event on the marker which would cause the infowindow to display.

Comment: That sounds good, however I'm still not quite sure how to access the marker via Javascript, I guess.

Comment: Looks to me like you have a  collection of the markers in `setmarkers`.

Comment: Or, you could use overlays instead of markers and add a CSS class:  https://humaan.com/blog/custom-html-markers-google-maps/

Comment: Yes, admittedly that other answer would have gotten me the same answer. Should I delete this question or something?

Comment: I don't think it is an exact duplicate of your question but the answer there could have helped you solve this issue, so that's why I also added a more direct answer. So I think we can leave it like that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the position of the marker in an array (if you know it) or you could assign your markers with some custom id property and trigger a click event on a specific marker based on that id.

```js
var map = null;
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787, -79.359741),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  // Setup three markers with info windows

  var point;

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.65654, -79.90138);
  createMarker(point, 'This is marker with id aaa', 'aaa');

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.91892, -78.89231);
  createMarker(point, 'This is marker with id abc', 'abc');

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.82589, -79.10040);
  createMarker(point, 'This is marker with id ccc', 'ccc');
}

function createMarker(latlng, html, id) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    myCustomId: id
  });
  
  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function clickMarker(id) {

  // Loop through markers array
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
  
    // Check custom id
    if (markers[i].myCustomId === id) {
    
      // Trigger marker click
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    }
  }
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<hr>
<button onClick="clickMarker('aaa')">Marker with id aaa</button>
<button onClick="clickMarker('abc')">Marker with id abc</button>
<button onClick="clickMarker('ccc')">Marker with id ccc</button>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this bit of code was what I needed: google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');

Comment: Glad it helped!